# postgresql truncate strings

Tags: postgresql, identifier, maxlength

I am working with a table-returning function on PostgreSQL (using pgAdmin 4). It used to work well but for some reason I get this error message when trying to modify the function:

> ERROR:  type "TABLE(id integer, id_scenario integer, date_valid
>   timestamp 
>       wit" does not exist
>       NOTICE:  identifier "TABLE(id integer, id_scenario integer, date_valid 
>       timestamp without time zone, dni_q95 double precision, csp_forecast_q95 
>       double precision, storage_q95 double precision)" will be truncated to 
>       "TABLE(id integer, id_scenario integer, date_valid timestamp wit"

I understand an identifier cannot be longer than 63 bytes, so my line of code gets truncated. I would be really grateful if someone could help me on these 2 questions:

1. Why is this line suddenly recognised as an identifier?
2. How to circumvent this problem, knowing that I need all of those columns returned?

Here is the function body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.csp_park_95(id_park integer)
RETURNS SETOF "TABLE(id integer, id_scenario integer, date_valid 
timestamp without time zone, dni_q95 double precision, csp_forecast_q95 
double precision, storage_q95 double precision)"
LANGUAGE 'sql'
COST 100.0
VOLATILE 
ROWS 1000.0
AS $function$

-- irrelevant code

$function$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.csp_park_95(integer)
OWNER TO "POC_kacare_admin";
```

Comment: "*Why is this line suddenly recognised as an identifier?"*  because double quotes are for identifiers: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove double-quotes as a follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.csp_park_95(id_park integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(id integer, id_scenario integer, date_valid 
    timestamp without time zone, dni_q95 double precision, csp_forecast_q95 
    double precision, storage_q95 double precision)
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    COST 100.0
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000.0
    AS $function$
    -- irrelevant code
    $function$;
```

Comment: It's not a bug in pgAdmin. Doubles quotes are used for identifers. So `"TABLE(id integer, id_scenario integer, date_valid 
    timestamp without time zone, dni_q95 double precision, csp_forecast_q95 
    double precision, storage_q95 double precision)"` is **one** name, not a name and a parameter list.

Comment: Yes, I know. But if I understand question correctly `"TABLE(id integer, id_scenario integer, date_valid timestamp without time zone, dni_q95 double precision, csp_forecast_q95 double precision, storage_q95 double precision)"` is not what op want, he said: _"2) How to circumvent this problem, knowing that I need all of those columns returned?"_.

Comment: Anyway I edited my answer to avoid pgAdmin4's bug speculations.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works after removing double quotes :) Sorry if my question was a bit naive, I'm new to postgresql.